# How to create 2-D lists of tuples from two 2-D lists in python?

Tags: python

I have two 2d lists, e.g:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Then how can I get one 2d list of tuples: [[(1,5), (2,6)], [(3,7), (4,8)]]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have answered your own question, as follows:

```
[[(i1,j1) for i1, j1 in zip(i, j)] for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

However, a simplified form exists, along similar lines but working directly with the tuples instead of unpacking them into multiple variables -- also the first list comprehension can be replaced by just calling `list` on the output of `zip`:

```
[list(zip(*t)) for t in zip(a,b)]
```

or alternatively:

```
vars = (a, b)
[list(zip(*t)) for t in zip(*vars)]
```

As well as being slightly simpler, this has the advantage that it is easier to generalise to more variables, for example if you had:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
c = [[9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

Then you could do:

```
vars = (a, b, c)

[list(zip(*t)) for t in zip(*vars)]
```

to give you:

```
[[(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10)], [(3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this code:

```
data = [[(i1,j1) for i1, j1 in zip(i, j)] for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```